# How to turn off python-mypy in spacemacs flycheck-mode?

Tags: spacemacs, python

I'm using the latest Spacemacs with the Python layer. I'd like to turn off `python-mypy` in `flycheck-mode`, but the following in my `~/.spacemacs` doesn't work:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-mypy)
)
```

How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

```
flycheck-disabled-checkers is a variable defined in ‘flycheck.el’.
Its value is nil

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘flycheck-symbol-list-p’.
  You can customize this variable.
```

This variable is a buffer-local variable.

When you call `add-to-list` on it, it was set as locally. Check out the example call from **ielm** below.

[image: buffer-local]

One possible option is to customize it using the `customize` interface to let it set globally for you.

---

Edit:

1. In fact you can set it in `.dir-locals.el`. This will set the variable for a lot of files ("directory local" variable is still file local, I might add). E.g. I tried setting the following (see below), and checkers are all disabled for every python file in the entire projectile dir.

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((python-mode . ((flycheck-disabled-checkers . (python-mypy python-flake8 python-pylint)))))
```

2. How to customize & set it globally once and for all

- Do `C-h v` (or `SPC h d v`, spacemacs only) and select `flycheck-disabled-checkers`.
- Click `customize` in the sentence "You can customize this variable.".
- In the interface, click `INS` to insert a value
- Enter `python-mypy` as you wish
- Click `State` and choose what you want
- You can try out in the current session only
- You can persist the customization for future use also
- OR you can revert if you mess up

Comment: I don't suppose it's customizable in `.dir-locals.el`?

Comment: Also, could you expand on how I might use the `customize` interface to set it globally?

Comment: @DavidEyk Edited. HTH.